# Relation of frequency of light and photocurrent in Photo-electric effect

Tags: frequency, photoelectric-effect

As we know that the frequency of incident light is postulated to have no effect on the photocurrent. But coming to think about both quantities should be related. Consider the formula-

                      Current(I)=q/t

> Also,   hν = Φ + KE
> ⇒ The higher the frequency of incident light (ν), the higher would be the kinetic energy of photoelectron (KE) for the same material. 
>    ⇒The velocity of the photoelectron will also increase.

⇒ The electron would be moving faster.

⇒Time taken to reach the collector plate is lesser and hence I increases.(From I=q/t)

Is this conclusion correct? Please point out if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> the frequency of incident light is postulated to have no effect on the photocurrent

This is true only if

1. The source is postulated to produce constant photon flux (rather than constant optical power) at the target as the frequency is varied.
2. The frequency is always high enough for the photon energy to overcome the work function of the material in which we're observing the photoelectric effect.

That said,

> Time taken to reach the collector plate is lesser and hence I increases.

This does not follow. *I* depends on the number of electrons reaching the collector per unit time, not on the latency between when some particular photoelectron is emitted and when it's collected.

Answer (score 0):

There's a sense in which this happens, but not the way you say. If the initial photoelectron has sufficient energy to ionize a nearby atom, the liberated electron adds to the photocurrent. The greater the energy of the photon, the more ionization. A 1 keV soft x-ray photon incident on a silicon detector yields about 280 electrons. Thus, the current is much more than 1 electron/photon.

Comment: You say "the greater the energy of the photon, the more ionization." The more ionization what? Current? Flux? Energy (per photo ionized electron)?

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer Electrons collected by your anode per photon.

Answer (score -1):

> As we know that the frequency of incident light is postulated to have
> no effect on the photocurrent.

This is just incorrect.